# c program is not waiting for input

Tags: c, scanf

I had made C program. (please, I am  beginner and very new in programing).It ask me for first input and then it doesn't wait or ask me to type another input and quits very fastly. I am using eclipse-cdt and Ubuntu.

**code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    float x1,x2,x3,y3,y2,y1,slope12,slope23;
    int exi;

    printf("this program finds that three point are co-linear or not. you just have to enter the value of the x and y's\n");
    printf("now enter the the value of x1 and y1 of point (x1,y2) here  here resplectevely :- ");
    scanf("%f%f",&x1,&y1);
    printf("now enter the value of the x2 and y2 of point (x2,y2) here respectively here :- ");
    scanf("%f%f",&x2,&y2);
    printf("now enter the value of x3 and y3 of point (x3,y3) here respectively :- ");
    scanf("%f%f",&x3,&y3);
    slope12=(y1-y2)/(x1-x2);
    slope23=(y2-y3)/(x2-x3);
    if(slope12==slope23)
        printf("\nthe points are co-liner and are in strait line");
    else
        printf("\nthe points are not in strait line and are not co-linear");
    ///delaying the program ending
    printf("\nenter any digit to exit");
    scanf("%d",&exi);
    printf("you enterd %d good bye",exi);

    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
 jos@jos-Aspire-5742:/media/jos/D/c progs/eclipse/linux/coliner-points/Debug$ ./coliner-points 
 this program finds that three point are co-linear or not. you just have to enter the value of the x and y's
 now enter the the value of x1 and y1 of point (x1,y2) here  here resplectevely :- 7,8
 now enter the value of the x2 and y2 of point (x2,y2) here respectively here :- now enter the value of x3 and y3 of point (x3,y3) here respectively :- 
 the points are not in strait line and are not co-linear
 enter any digit to exityou enterd 0 good byejos@jos-Aspire-5742:/media/jos/D/c progs/eclipse/linux/coliner-points/Debug$
```

is there any wrong or error in my codes??

Comment: Don't type the comma; your scanf is looking for a space between the numbers.

Comment: Works for me? Except that the output is wrong (It always tells me that the points are not on a straigth line), which results presumably from the float comparison, and it could be an improvement if you use this link: http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1352443831&id=1043284392 as fix for your newline problem.

Comment: @Scott Hunter  thanks it works

Comment: Aside: there is no need to risk a divide by zero error. You can do this by cross-multiplying: `if((y1-y2) * (x2-x3) == (y2-y3) * (x1-x2)) { /* colinear */ }`, and use an epsilon too as advised by @arc_lupus.

Comment: @Weather Vane yes!! this is acutely easy way thanks. i am new to c, thus i didn't thought this through.

Comment: ...also, never use the inferior `float` unless there is a good reason why you cannot use `double`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first scanf is missing the comma, so it matches only the first %f. The rest all therefore have pending input to process, but it begins with a comma, so they all fail to match any input.

You need to check return values to make sure you got the number of values you were expecting.

Comment: all hail you.program runs fine now.so i can not use comma(   ,   ) to separates the input values ??

Comment: You can if you look for it. The input has to match the scanf format string.

Answer (score 1):

Always check the return value of `scanf()`, eg

```
if (scanf("%f,%f", &x2, &y2) != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "scanf failed at line %d.\n", __LINE__ - 1);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```